# Explode and Pipe in a $_GET variable

Tags: php, pipe, explode

I am passing some data using the URL and I'm trying to use a pipe to seperate the different parts of the data. For example, one of the pieces I'm trying to send is a course code such as "COP211|212|213" and I have a function that will explode these pieces

```
explode("|",$code);
```

where $code is from the url -- something like coursecode.php?q=COP211|212|213

The issue is that explode isn't doing anything! I have tried explode('|', explode("|", explode("/|" and nothing works, the string comes through with pipes intact.
Specifically,

```
strpos($code, "|");
```

always returns FALSE.

**Editing to clarify**

```
var_dump($code);
if(strpos($code, "|") !== FALSE) { // Manage slashed courses
    $cid = explode("|", $code);
}
var_dump($cid);
```

var_dump($code) returns the string, all in one piece.

strpos($code, "|") ALWAYS returns false, even if | is present.

var_dump($cid) is not an array, it is the string again.

Is this an encoding issue or something since it's coming through the URL first?

Help!

Comment: Do a `var_dump($code)` and post the result.

Comment: Try echoing $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] first to see what data is actually being received by your script.

Comment: var_dump($code) returns the string, all in one piece.

Comment: I figured out what I was doing wrong, I was feeding an array to explode() instead of a string. No wonder it wasn't working.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure `$_GET` contains something by using `var_dump($_GET)`.

Your second problem is `explode()` *returns* the exploded string as an array. To replace the contents of `$code`, do this:

```
$code = explode('|', $code);
```

Comment: I expect an array, because I then need to iterate through it to put the COP part back onto the subsequent numbers. The final output is going to be something like COP120 COP122, etc but I have to be able to explode the string first! I've edited to clarify where I'm using various parts so that you can see what's going on.